# Не отрабатывает слушатель повешенный на синглтон

Tags: java, android

Цель получить доступ к `MediaPlayer` из любого класса, чтобы в любой момент поставить на паузу или начать воспроизводить другую мелодию. Можно было создать в подклассе `Application` статический экземпляр `MediaPlayer`, но нужны еще методы для обработки того, какая мелодия сейчас будет играть, метод для освобождения ресурсов и так далее. Всем этим я не захотел нагромождать подкласс `Application`, тем более что у него уже есть метод, который мне возвращает его контекст, чтобы я мог в синглтоне инициализировать `MediaPlayer`. В итоге я создал отдельный класс синглтон.

```
public class MediaPlayerSingleton implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private static MediaPlayerSingleton mpSingleton;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    private MediaPlayerSingleton() {
    }

    static MediaPlayerSingleton getInstance() {
        if (mpSingleton == null) mpSingleton = new MediaPlayerSingleton();
        return mpSingleton;
    }


    void play() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.raw.melodiya);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
      releaseMP();
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.raw.acdc);
    }

    private void releaseMP(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null){
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
```

И теперь на некой активности вызываю метод `getInstance.play();` Но по окончанию воспроизведения слушатель не срабатывает. Думаю я зря полагал, что он сработает, так как класс  не наследник `Activity`, который находится в фокусе. Видать тут без `Service` не обойтись? Или всё таки есть какой нибудь способ реализовать слушатель без сервиса? Наверно, если поставить слушатели на все активности, то такое бы сработало, но выглядит не очень.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо, наверное, еще вызвать `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this)` при запуске (или создании каждого инстанса), а то откуда он знает, кто ждет окончания музыки?

Comment: Да, точно, я упустил этот момент. Добавил в код, но я думаю это никак не меняют ситуации. Не срабатывает слушатель

Comment: Гм. Но вообще-то это единственный способ дать понять медиаплееру, что нужно вызвать onCompletion, нет?

Comment: хм.. вроде срабатывает слушатель, логи поставил и они отрабатывают. Пишет о другой ошибке

Comment: Да и ошибка была не по делу. Я тупо в Callback забыл дописать mediaPlayer.start();  В общем две глупые ошибки. А то я уже начал думать, что изначальная моя идея с синглтоном для глобального слушателя  была неверной.